# Term for "functions that have a closed-form expression in terms of base functions $B$"?

Tags: terminology

Suppose we have a set of "basic" functions $B=\{+,-,\cdot,/,\exp,\log,\sin \}$, and we want to define:

> The set of functions $F_B$ which can be defined as $f(x)=\textit{application of elements of }B$.

Is there a term for this? I originally thought that "algebraic functions" referred to the set $F_B$ for $B=\{+,-,\cdot,/,\text{power}_{q\in\mathbb Q}\}$, until I found out about the [Abel-Ruffini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) theorem.

I'd like a general natural language term for $F$. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

I would call them *$B$-based* or *$B$-generated* functions.